# Lazy dropdown in Grails

Tags: performance, grails

im trying to implement in Grails autofilter like in Excel. My idea is to create a Taglib

```
class FilterPanelTagLib {
static namespace = 'x'
def filterPanel = {attrs, body ->

    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer()
    List lines = attrs.lines
    def filter = attrs.filter
    out << "<form>"
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    attrs.columns.each{col->
        if(col != ''){
            List tmp = getColumnValues(lines,col)
            def value = filter?filter[col]:""
            out << "<th>" + g.select(
                onchange:"submit()",
                name:"filter."+col,
                from:tmp, 
                value:value, 
                noSelection:['ALL':'ALL'])+"</th>"
        }else {
            out << "<th> </th>"
        }
    }
    out << "</form>"
    println ((System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/1000 + " filterPanelTagLib".center(40,"-"))

}

private List getColumnValues(List lines, String column){
    List result = lines.collect{it[column]}.unique().sort() << 'ALL'
    return result
}
```

and use it in GSPs like this:

```
<x:filterPanel filter="${filter}" lines="${taskList}" columns="['id',
        'label',
        'activity',
        'assignee'
        '',
        '']"/>
```

It works fine. I get the values for selected dropboxes as params.filter in controller and can use criteriaBuilder to get the filtered list.

The problem is the performance for creating the content of each dropdown. I have tested it for a list with 1000 items and it takes about 3 sec. The target performance is <2 sec for 30.000

Any suggestion is wellcome!

Comment: Can't you use autosuggest inputs ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with autosuggest. How does it work?

Comment: Look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/